# Vscode extension use variable outside of function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hello within a vscode extension.js I cannot use the variable "chunk" outside of the function it is inside of:

```
let http = require('http');
let keyname = "key.key";
http.get('http://mysite.nl/vscode/?with=data', function(res) {
  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("INSIDE: " + chunk);
  });
});
vscode.window.showInformationMessage("OUSIDE FUNCTION:" + chunk); /*this does not work*/
```

edit: (tried to make a global variable, but I fail so much at javascript, is this supposed to work?)

```
let globalvar;
let http = require('http');
let keyname = "key.key";
http.get('http://mysite.nl/vscode/?with=data', function(res) {
  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("INSIDE: " + chunk);
    globalvar = chunk;
  });
});
vscode.window.showInformationMessage("OUSIDE FUNCTION:" + globalvar); /*this does not work*/
```

Comment: you cannot do this in [tag:javascript]

Comment: your code is async you can't get the value of `chunk` before you set it  .... also `chunk` is not visible outside the callback.

Comment: assign it to some global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for two reasons. First of all, function arguments are local to the function they belong to:

```js
function foo(bar) {
    console.log("Inside function: %s", typeof bar);
    function inner(){
      console.log("In function's scope: %s", typeof bar);
    }
    inner();
}

foo("Hi");
console.log("Elsewhere: %s", typeof bar);
```

Secondly, `http.get()` starts fetching the URL in another thread and continues executing the rest of the program, i.e. it calls `vscode.window.showInformationMessage()` immediately. The variable does not even exist yet so, even if you didn't have scope issues, there would be nothing to print. Then, some time later (even if only a few milliseconds) the GET request completes. **If** it succeeded then `function(chunk) {}` gets finally called—too late!

```js
let globalvar;
window.setTimeout(function (chunk){
    console.log("Done! Chunk is %s", chunk);
    globalvar = chunk;
}, 2000, "Hi!");
console.log("Chunk? %s", typeof globalvar);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for that explanation! Guess I will have to make another piece of codethat does it in one line, something like that